# Does signing of the JWT require internet access?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, jwt

JWT process is to sign JWT and use JWT to retrieve an access token. This access token is used to call Google APIs.

We use Google auth library to sign JWT. IS this signing process container locally or does it require internet access to another service to sign the JWT?

Comment: Not only will you need internet access to request an access token you will also need internet access to access the api.  Access tokens are created on the authorization server.  So to create one you need to be able to contact that server.  Also APIs are also running on a web server.

Comment: Depends on where the private Key for signing is stored. You sign with you private key and when you send your jwt to google to request the AccessToken google needs the public Key to verify your jwt.

What kind of Flow is this? It's not one of the usual OAuth 2.0 Grants, is it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the flow for retrieving the access token using the service account, for example, when it sees the script for retrieving the access token using Javascript, the value of jwt can be created without the web access. But, when the access token is retrieved using the jwt, it is required to access the endpoint of Google like `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/GetAccessTokenFromServiceAccount_js/blob/master/getaccesstokengromserviceaccount_js.js)

The script for retrieving the access token using the service account is as follows.

```js
const private_key = "###"; // private_key of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
const client_email = "###"; // client_email of JSON file retrieved by creating Service Account
const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"]; // Scopes

const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
const header = { alg: "RS256", typ: "JWT" };
const now = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
const claim = {
  iss: client_email,
  scope: scopes.join(" "),
  aud: url,
  exp: (now + 3600).toString(),
  iat: now.toString(),
};
const signature = btoa(JSON.stringify(header)) + "." + btoa(JSON.stringify(claim));
const sign = new JSEncrypt();
sign.setPrivateKey(private_key);
const jwt = signature + "." + sign.sign(signature, CryptoJS.SHA256, "sha256");
const params = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    assertion: jwt,
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
  }),
};
const obj = await fetch(url, params).then((res) => res.json()).catch((err) => console.log(err));
console.log(obj);
```

#### Referencs:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)
- [GetAccessTokenFromServiceAccount_js](https://github.com/tanaikech/GetAccessTokenFromServiceAccount_js)